# Is there a shortcut to restore desktop focus?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

Perhaps I'm missing something, but I've recently started using Unity on Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm getting used to it. But, whenever I start a program and then exit the program I must click on the desktop, otherwise the keyboard shortcuts to move between workspaces (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cursor Key</kbd>) don't work.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to restore the focus to the Ubuntu Desktop or must I use the mouse?

Answer (score 2):

Try holding the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, maybe you know it as the "Windows" key. It should show you many of the shortcuts you can use in Ubuntu.

I think the one you're looking for is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't seem to be quite it either. Ctrl+Super+d does give me back the desktop, but only if I had something running in the workspace. If I close all apps in the workspace the Windows Title in the upper left is blank. Only when I click on the desktop does the upper left change to "Ubuntu Desktop". I can then change workspaces with Ctrl+Alt+Arrow. But the who;e point is to not use the mouse as much.

Comment: Then I wouldn't know, sounds like a bug: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: This is certainly a bug.  Not sure when it was introduced but it is very annoying and happens to me as well.  It should refocus on to the last application prior to the one which was closed or return you back to the desktop focus.